# Absolute Colors in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am a aware that Kivy uses tinted colors such that a widget will be colored according to the color of its parent widget. Is there a way I can circumvent this nuance such that I can supply an RGBA value to the child without having to change the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colours *are* absolute, and widgets aren't tinted according to the colour of their parent.

Are you perhaps referring to the Button widget, where the background_color applies a tint to the background_normal image? If so, just set the background_normal property to `''` which just makes the Button plain white such that the colour is applied without modification, e.g. in kv:

```
# Assuming YourButton is a Button subclass defined in Python
<YourButton>: 
    background_normal: ''
```

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, how should RGBA values be specified? Are the RGB values from 0 to 255 and A from 0 to 1? Or are they all from 0 to 1?

Comment: They are from 0 to 1.